# preg_match_all with callback?

Tags: php, string, callback, preg-match-all, numeric

I'm interested in replace numeric matches in real time and manipulate them to hexadecimal.

I was wonder if it's possible without using foreach loop.

so iow...

every thing in between :

`=` {numeric value} `;`

will be manupulated to :

`=` {hexadecimal numeric value} `;`

```
preg_match_all('/\=[0-9]\;/',$src,$matches);
```

Is there any callback to preg_match_all so instead of preform a loop afterwards I can manipulate them as soon as preg_match_all catch every match (real time).

this is not correct syntax but just so you can get the idea :

```
preg_match_all_callback('/\=[0-9]\;/',$src,$matches,{convertAll[0-9]ToHexadecimal});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

You would match them with a regex like `/=\d+?;/` and then your callback would look like...

```
function($matches) { return dechex($matches[1]); }
```

Combined, it gives us...

```
preg_replace_callback('/=(\d+?);/', function($matches) { 
   return dechex($matches[1]);
}, $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IDqwpK).

Alternatively, you could use positive lookbehind/forward to match the delimiters and then pass `'dechex'` straight as the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [T-Regx tool](https://t-regx.com), which is far better! (automatic delimiters, exceptions instead of warnings, cleaner API)

```
pattern('=(\d+?);')->replace($str)->group(1)->callback('dechex');
```

or if you prefer the anonymous function

```
pattern('=(\d+?);')->replace($str)->group(1)->callback(function (Group $group) {
    return dechex($group);
});
```